# Running Perl executables in git-bash

Tags: perl, git-bash, shebang

I tried to run script in git bash command line and I saw:
`"use: command not found"`
When I changed sh file from 
`'./clean_translations.pl'` to '`perl ./clean_translations.pl'`
After that script works.

I have win 8.1. Path is as in other PC (win 7).
What should I change to works without 'perl'?

Edit: echo $PATH:

```
/c/Users/PBI/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/PBI/bin:/c/usr/bin:/c/strawberry/c/bin:/c/strawberry/perl/bin:/c/straw
berry/perl/site/bin:/c/strawberry/c/lib:/c/strawberry/perl/site/lib:/c/strawberr
y/perl/lib:/c/Program Files (x86)/ActiveState Komodo IDE 8:/c/instantclient_12_1
:/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin:/c/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_91/bin:/c/
Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client:/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client:/c/Wind
ows/system32:/cmd:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/Window
sPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DA
L:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/c/Prog
ram Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/c/Program Files (x86)
/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/c/Program Files (x86)/ATI Tech
nologies/ATI.ACE/Core-Static:/c/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions:/bin:/mingw64/
bin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

Comment: What does the ***`bush`*** GIT command do?

Comment: What does this have to do with Git?

Comment: What does `type -a perl` say?

Comment: $ type -a perl
perl is /c/strawberry/perl/bin/perl
perl is /c/usr/bin/perl

Comment: Then you probably need to put one of those in your `#!` line.

Comment: With `#!/c/usr/bin/perl` same problem, with `#!/c/strawberry/perl/bin/perl` syntax problem. So it isn't the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

Add this as the first line of the script:

`#!/usr/bin/env perl`

This conveys that the script should be run using Perl interpreter.

If you are running the script on windows shebang is not parsed. The file extension(.pl) is used to decide the interpreter. In a `bash` shell shebang is necessary.

Comment: @PiotrBielski, `#!/bin/bash` executes the script as a bash script. Please modify it as suggested and try

Comment: When I used #!/usr/bin/env perl is "No such file or directory" when I changed to #!/usr/bin/ perl is bad interpreter. 
 #!/usr/bin/perl => Command not found

Comment: @PiotrBielski, do `echo $PATH` in git-bash and post the result

Comment: @PiotrBielski Like melpomene suggested put one of `#!/c/strawberry/perl/bin/perl` or `#!/c/usr/bin/perl` in the first line and try.

Comment: With `#!/c/usr/bin/perl` same problem, with #!/c/strawberry/perl/bin/perl' syntax problem. So it isnt the solution.

Comment: Changes encoding from UTF-8 to UTF-8 without BOM.